# Archive to bottom of file in emacs org-mode

Tags: configuration, org-mode

I'd like my archive to go to the bottom of the current file, not a separate .org_archive file. How do I configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure `org-archive-location`, where you can set up a heading in your file for archiving:

> "::* Archived Tasks"
>         Archive in the current file, under the top-level headline
>         "* Archived Tasks".

Full doc here: http://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html#org-archive-location